# Devise writes only local IP adress in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ip

On my production rails server devise gem logs 127.0.0.1 into database as remote user IP.

What should I do to collect real user IP, not localhost like on development.

My production server setup:

`Rails 5.0.3`
`devise (4.3.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.0)`
`passenger from my hosting provider`

I don't use load balancer.

[image]

Comment: are you running rails application locally in production environment?

Comment: Please elaborate on your production server setup. Do you use a load balancer? What server do you use?

Comment: I'm having this same issue using Google Cloud on my rails app

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but I was looking at the devise gem **[devise/lib/devise/models/trackable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/trackable.rb#L20-L31)** and found out where they are saving the IP address

This is taking the current_sign_in_ip - The remote IP updated when the user signs in.

I hope that this helps or at least points you in the right direction